# Strange characters and encoding while using twitter API

Tags: php, api, twitter, character-encoding, special-characters

I begun developing my own SIMPLE twitter client in my server (to bypass twitter.com blocking rule stablished by some dumbass at govt. office)

Please check this image so you can see **the accented characters converted into weird symbol**:

[image: Screenshot of my app]

It is being developed with this class [Twitter PHP class by Tijs Verkoyen](http://classes.verkoyen.eu/twitter/)

This is my heading code, which is utf-8. **Can anyone point me to a fix?**

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Your link to the class set off google's RED PAGE OF DANGER. But anyways, how are you getting your requests back? rss, json, or xml? From http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Things-Every-Developer-Should-Know it only says calls as xml are utf-8, but it doesn't mention the other two so I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: I thought it was XML by default, but the class docs isn't very specific about it... I'll keep researching. http://classes.verkoyen.eu/twitter/docs#getfriendstimeline

Comment: Are you perhaps having browser specific issues? For example I've had similar issues with some Linux browsers. You should also check that the actual text you output is UTF-8 encoded not just that the HTML page is tagged as UTF-8.

Comment: I have the same issue with all the browsers I try the app. Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE, Firefox (all on Windows. Doesn't have *nix here atm). How should I check that the actual text I output is UTF-8 and not only the HTML with meta tag? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using the `utf8_encode()` function with PHP

Comment: @DimitarChristoff: Where do I exactly put it and what do I have to write exactly for utf8_encode()??Will this do:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8_encode()" />`

Comment: no. charset is utf8. this is when you process data before you output. eg. `$tweet['text'] = utf8_decode($tweet['text']);`

Comment: I took this approach before arriving here. While it appears to work, it turns fancy quotes (the character equivalent of ldquo, rdquo) into ? in the string.

Answer (score 1):

best is to avoid hassle if you could pass all your twitter texts(i.e. twitter API delivers JSON format too) using some sort of JSON format and  pass those JSON into PHP 5 function

```
json_decode(jsonStr);
```

json_decode automatically converts to utf8 encoding which can save you from writing extra code for character encoding..